# html5 label element with multiple labelable descendants

Tags: html, label, w3c-validation

So I am going through and validating my site and I notice 9 errors but this one has me stumped.

```
Line 96, Column 27: label element with multiple labelable descendants.
                    <label><h1>Birthday</h1>
```

the full code below:

```
<label><h1>Birthday</h1>
                        <select name="day">
                            <option value="00" disabled selected>Day</option>
                            <?php
                            for($i=1;$i<=31; $i++)
                            {
                               $n = sprintf("%02s", $i);
                               echo '<option value="'.$n.'">'.$n.'</option>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <select name="month">
                            <option value="00" disabled selected>Month</option>
                            <?php
                            for($i=1;$i<=12; $i++)
                            {
                               $n = sprintf("%02s", $i);
                               echo '<option value="'.$n.'">'.date("F",strtotime('01.'.$n.'.2001')).'</option>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <select name="year">
                            <option value="00" disabled selected>Year</option>
                            <?php
                                $year = date("Y");
                            for($i=$year-99;$i<=$year; $i++)
                            {

                               echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </label>
```

any suggestions I know it must do with either the h1 after the label or something along the lines because there are no label in labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple `select` elements within the `label`, and the selects are all “labelable”.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element

The spec actually says that “If […] the label element has a labelable element descendant, then the first such descendant in tree order is the label element's labeled control.”, so in your example the browser should treat the label as a label for the fist select element.